# tracking multiple files in uploadcare

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadcare

This is [uploadcare](http://uploadcare.com) question.

we have `.done() .fail() .progress()` in `fileFrom()` for single file so we can tracking the upload file.

But we don't have `.done() .fail() .progress()` in `filesFrom() multiple files, how can we track the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uploadcare.filesFrom()` returns array of files, each one has `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.progress()`.

E.g:

```
    var files = uploadcare.filesFrom('uploaded', [uuid1, uuid2, uuid3]);
    $.each(files, function(i, f) {
        f.done(console.log);
    })
```